# The difference between "almost" and "nearly"

Tags: difference, usage

What's the difference in using between "almost" and "nearly"? In what cases they can be used interchangeably and in which ones they can't?

Comment: The only difference I can see is that "almost" can't be intensified the way "nearly" can: "We very nearly had an accident" works, but "We very almost had an accident" doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nearly** can almost always be replaced with **almost**.  However, there is a rare use of **nearly** to mean *closely* ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nearly) gives the example "more nearly related", meaning "more closely related" - here "almost" wouldn't work).

In its other, more common usage, **nearly** has the same meaning as **almost**, although perhaps **almost** is slightly stronger.  (ODO, the full OED and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/almost) all define "almost" as "very nearly" - although all three also define "nearly" as "almost".)

Most of the time when we say **almost**, we could just as well say **nearly**.  However, **almost** also has a use that **nearly** doesn't.

Even though ODO only gives one [definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/almost) for **almost**, the word **nearly** would work as a substitute in some of the examples it gives and not in others.

For example, either word could be used in these sentences:

> ‘he almost knocked Georgina over’
>
> ‘the place was almost empty’
>
> ‘blues, jazz—he can play almost anything’

But **almost** is the only possibility in the following examples:

> ‘There was almost a sense that if we did not say the word the problem would go away.’
>
> ‘The waters of Loch an Eilean were flat calm and the stillness of the air almost eerie.’
>
> ‘It was almost as if the local wildlife had decided to put on a show just to entertain us.’

In the sentences above, **almost** doesn't mean "nearly".  It means something more like "more or less".

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/almost-or-nearly) explains that:

> We use almost (but not nearly) to soften statements:
>
> - *I almost wish I hadn’t offered to pay his fine.*
>
> We use *almost* before *any* and before negative words such as *no, none, never, nobody, nothing*. We don’t use *nearly* in this way:
>
> - *Using this special software, you can find the history of almost any building.*
> - *They’ve almost no confidence that they can use the new phone properly.*
> - *She almost never raises her voice.*

To my ear, I don't think "nearly any" sounds unacceptable, but "nearly no" and "nearly never" are distinctly unidiomatic.

Comment: "you can find the history of nearly any building" sounds perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

A brief addition to @rjpond's answer:

1. In negative sentences, it's *nearly*, not *almost*, that can be used:

> I nearly didn’t make it to work on time today.

Also, *nearly* is used in the "*not nearly as [adjective] as*" construction:

> He’s not nearly as smart as he thinks he is.

2. *Nearly* is usually followed by numbers, e.g., *nearly 200 people.*
3. *Almost* may often be  followed by adverbs and adjectives, e.g., *almost always, almost certainly, almost impossible*.